# Concatenating multiple columns of pandas data frame including boolean values in few columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python. In my project I need to concatenate multiple columns of a pandas data frame to create a derived column. My data frame contains few columns with only TRUE & FALSE value. I'm using following code to do the concatenation operation

```
df_input["combined"] = [' '.join(row) for row in df_input[df_input.columns[0:]].values]
```

I'm getting following error while running the code

```
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, bool found
```

Can you expert please help me to solve the problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have a sample input and expected output you could update this question with.  You will receive better help if you follow [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the `Bool` columns with `astype(str)` and use a vectorized version to concatenate the columns as follows

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

st = """
col1|col2|col3
1|hello|True
4|world|False
7|!|True
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), sep="|")

print("my sample dataframe")
print(df.head())

print("current columns data types")
print(df.dtypes)

print("combining all columns with mixed datatypes") 
df["combined"] = df["col1"].astype(str)+" "+df["col2"]+ " " +df["col3"].astype(str)

print("here's how the data looks now")
print(df.head())

print("here are the new columns datatypes")
print(df.dtypes)
```

The output of the script:

```
my sample dataframe
   col1   col2   col3
0     1  hello   True
1     4  world  False
2     7      !   True
current columns data types
col1     int64
col2    object
col3      bool
dtype: object
combining all columns with mixed datatypes
here's how the data looks now
   col1   col2   col3       combined
0     1  hello   True   1 hello True
1     4  world  False  4 world False
2     7      !   True       7 ! True
here are the new columns datatypes
col1         int64
col2        object
col3          bool
combined    object
dtype: object
```

As you can see the new `combined` contains the concatenate data.

### Dynamic concatenation

To perform the concatenation dynamically, here's how you should edit my previous example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

st = """
col1|col2|col3
1|hello|True
4|world|False
7|!|True
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), sep="|")

print("my sample dataframe")
print(df.head())

print("current columns data types")
print(df.dtypes)

print("combining all columns with mixed datatypes") 
#df["combined"] = df["col1"].astype(str)+" "+df["col2"]+ " " +df["col3"].astype(str)

all_columns = list(df.columns) 
df["combined"] = "" 

for index, column_name in enumerate(all_columns):
    print("current column {column_name}".format(column_name=column_name))
    df["combined"] = df["combined"] + " " +df[column_name].astype(str)

print("here's how the data looks now")
print(df.head())

print("here are the new columns datatypes")
print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott Boston & @MedAli.But I need to concatenate it dynamically. So, I'm using following code which Scott mentioned `df["combined"] = [' '.join(row.astype(str)) for row in df[df.columns[0:]].values]` . But problem is that I'm getting repeating output at combined table. For example first row of my output is looking like `1 hello True 1 hello True`
 while I'm using  MedAli's data

Comment: @PythonLearner check my updated answer to handle dynamic concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `astype`:

```
df_input["combined"] = [' '.join(row.astype(str)) for row in df_input[df_input.columns[0:]].values]
```